# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product-1')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

So I am trying to display JSON data in my React.js project, but I am getting an error that I can't figure out. I've spent 2 days trying to figure it out, but had no luck

The JSON data: (filename: products.json)

```json
{
    "product-1": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "product-1",
        }
    ],

    "product-2": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "product-2",
        }
    ],

    "product-3": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "product-3",
        }
    ]
}
```

My javascript:

```js
  const productsData = Object.keys(backendData).map(key => {
    return {
        [key]: backendData[key]
    }
  })

  console.log(productsData[0].products["product-1"][0].id)
```

error:
[image]

Log of backEndData:
[image]

Comment: Why would `productsData[0].products` be defined?

Comment: @Bravo because it console.logs all the possible outcomes.

Comment: Let me ask another way that you may understand. There is no property created that is named products. Where do you think your code created such a property

Comment: @Bravo well idk but when I just console log productsData[0] it logs this property called products which then when I open it, it has the json data

Comment: No it doesn't. Not with the code in the question

Comment: @Bravo yes it does for me

Comment: Try `Object.keys(backendData.products)`

Comment: Then you haven't shown real data or real code

Answer (score 0):

Because `productsData` will return you array like this:

```
    [ 
        { "product-1": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "product-1",
            }
        ]}, 
        {"product-2": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "product-2",
            }
        ]}, .... 
    ]
```

Meaning this is array of objects, where each object have one key-value pair, where key is name and value is an array.
If you want to access id then you should do like this:

```
productsData[0]["product-1"][0].id
```

**UPDATED AFTER UPDATE OF OP**

Since your `backendData` value does not match product.json, I will ignore that product.json and write you the solution which will work for the value of `backendData` you just provided.

```
const productsData = backendData.products;
const id = productsData[0]["product-1"][0].id;
```

Comment: When I try that I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Comment: It is working, check screenshot here https://ibb.co/WnDt0Gy

Comment: I swear it's not working for me for some reason

Comment: Only explanation for that is that your `backendData` is not javascript object representation of that products.json you provided in OP. It would be helpful to upload log of `backendData` so we can see what it actually is.

Comment: Ok I updated it. You can see the log of backenddata in the thread

Comment: So I was right, your product.json does not match your backendData value, in provided json there is no `products` attribute anywhere. I dont know how and why this happened to you, you need to debug on you own, but I will update my answer with working example for backendData structure you just provided with screenshot.